# What are different options available to get Azure Active Directory user profile update notification to Azure function?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

What are the different options provided by `Microsoft` to get a user profile update notification to a specified `HTTPS` endpoint?

I found one solution which is `change notification` using `graph API subscriptions` for the specified resources. But it expires in 3 days and again need to subscribe for the same user after 3 days.

Is there anything like a one-time configuration and we will get a notification?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware that there is one-time configuration available. Rather i would suggest you to [create the subscription first time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), then you can use [update subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (so that you can renew it, before the 3 days timeframe).